# Bash function that returns value and prints error message

Tags: bash, shell-script

Is it possible to write a function that prints an error although the function is used to return a parameter?

I tried this, but it won't work...

```
my_function() {
    echo "return value"
    >&2 echo "error message"
}

echo $(my_function) >> /dev/null
```

I expect the console output

```
error message
```

EDIT:
Actually works like this.

Comment: What exactly does "won't work" mean, what do you get? When I try this, my output matches your expectation.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Had a typo while testing... @DonHolgo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completion:

```
my_function() {
    echo "return value"
    >&2 echo "error message"
}

MY_VAR=$(my_function)

echo $MY_VAR
```

Gives me now the exact output I want in the right order:

```
error message
return value
```

Answer (score 0):

Use just `my_function 1>/dev/null`.

```
$ my_function() {
    echo "return value";
    >&2 echo "error message";
}

$ my_function 1>/dev/null
error message

$ my_function 2>/dev/null
return value
```